# error: 'timezone' was not declared in time.h

Tags: c++, xilinx-ise

Real simple program:

```
#include <time.h>
main()
{
    timezone;
}
```

The compile error I'm getting:

```
error: 'timezone' was not declared in this scope
```

On my Ubuntu machine this program compiles just fine using the standard `time.h` that [looks just like this](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/time.h;h=eb7549ddf46c654ed7436305c9272b0b136379ee;hb=master). You can find lines that look related to defining `timezone`...

```
275 /* Defined in localtime.c.  */
278 extern long int __timezone;     /* Seconds west of UTC.  */
290 # if defined __USE_SVID || defined __USE_XOPEN
292 extern long int timezone;
293 # endif
```

Now the slightly more complex part where I get the error. I'm trying to build this program with [Xilinx ISE](http://elinux.org/Xilinx_SDK_in_standard_Eclipse_software) to run on an embedded ARM chip. Xilinx provides all the standard C and C++ libraries and headers, such as `time.h`. But the Xilinx provided `time.h` doesn't seem to define `timezone` properly. This is the only line related to `timezone`:

```
extern __IMPORT long _timezone;
```

I'm not completely sure what to make of that. An explanation would be apprecatied. It seems awfully bizarre that a standard library would be implement improperly, even a specialized version optimized for an ARM chip. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: There's no `timezone` in C++. It's a [POSIX thing](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/timezone.html). I don't know whether Xilinx claims to provide a POSIX compliant environment, but it is not at all clear why an embedded platform would necessarily know what timezone it's in.

Comment: @n.m. According to Xilinx website "XSDK includes user-customizable drivers for all supported Xilinx hardware IPs, POSIX compliant kernel library and networking and file handling libraries." Would `time.h` be considered a kernel library? And do you have any guess what `extern __IMPORT long _timezone;` is trying to do?

Comment: No idea .......

Comment: My guess is that `__IMPORT` indicates that the symbol should be imported from a dynamic library, like `__declspec(dllimport)` for MSVC.